# I need change color of selected letters on ngx-admin nebular theme

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, nebular

I'm working with the [Nebula Theme](https://akveo.github.io/ngx-admin/) and i need to change the color of the active text. With the default theme, the letters of an 'a' tag or others active tags turn to Blue. I need turn to green color.

[image: color menue]

How can i edit the theme colors?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Nebular menu documentation](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/menu/theme#nbmenucomponent) you can set your own color variables for a lot of different cases, including element states. In your particular case, you need to set the value of the variable `menu-item-icon-active-color` and `menu-item-active-text-color` to the color you would like.

Since you are using ngx-admin, you can open the file `src/app/@theme/styles/themes.scss` and add the following line in the first nb-register-theme block:

```
$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  menu-item-icon-active-color: green,
  menu-item-active-text-color: green //this is what you need to add
  .. //rest of the variables
  ..
```

[image: Green menu item]